# Need explanation of memcpy from 3d array to 1d array

Tags: c++, arrays

Why can't I use memcpy to flatten 3d dynamic allocated array to 1d array?

What is the difference between storage of 3d and 1d dynamic allocated array?

Thanks for your attention.I would be really appreciate if you could give some explanation/links/books.

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{               
        float ***b;
        int i,j,k;
        int ntab=26,ncrss=3,nsubs=1;
        b=(float***)malloc(ntab*ncrss*nsubs*sizeof(float));
        for(i=0;i<nsubs;i++)
        {
                b[i]=(float**)malloc(ncrss*ntab*sizeof(float));
                for(j=0;j<ncrss;j++)
                {
                        b[i][j]=(float*)malloc(ntab*sizeof(float));
                }
        }
        for(i=0;i<nsubs;i++)
                for(j=0;j<ncrss;j++)
                        for(k=0;k<ntab;k++)
                                b[i][j][k]=k;
        for(i=0;i<nsubs;i++)
                for(j=0;j<ncrss;j++)
                        for(k=0;k<ntab;k++)
                                printf("b[%d][%d][%d]=%f\n",i,j,k,b[i][j][k]);
        float *a;
        a=(float*)malloc(ntab*ncrss*nsubs*sizeof(float));
        //memcpy(a,b,ntab*ncrss*nsubs*sizeof(float));
        for(i=0;i<nsubs;i++)
        {
                const int index1=i*ncrss*ntab;
                for(j=0;j<ncrss;j++)
                {
                        const int index2=j*ntab+index1;
                        for(k=0;k<ntab;k++)
                        {
                                a[index2]=b[i][j][k];
                        }
                }
        }
        for(i=0;i<ntab*ncrss*nsubs;i++)
                printf("a[%d]=%f\n",i,a[i]);

        return 0;
}
```

Comment: Because what you have allocated is not a true 3D array. It simulates one such that you can use array index notation to access it. But it is not technically a 3D array which needs to be contiguous in memory.

Comment: Your code makes a pointer pointing to a dynamically allocated array of pointers which point to an array of pointers etc. etc.  , this is a way of implementing the programming concept "3-d array" using non-contiguous blocks   , but clearly it is not a single contiguous block.  Some people object to even using the term "3-d array" to describe such a thing, although in the C standard there are strictly no multidimensional arrays of any sort  (there may be arrays of arrays, or arrays of pointers, recursively).

Comment: Thanks!@M.M I have been mistaken that this "3D array" storage in a single contigous block.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The 3d dynamic array which was constructed in the code snippet is a pointer to an array of pointers to arrays of pointers to arrays of values.
[image]

When memcpy is used with b as the source, it means the array to which b points to is copied. It means the array of pointers to arrays of pointers to arrays of values is copied.

In this case, the line

```
//memcpy(a,b,ntab*ncrss*nsubs*sizeof(float));
```

copies `ntab*ncrss*nsubs*sizeof(float)` bytes starting from the address to which b points to.

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much for your help and your figure,it really help me to understanding the allocate.

Answer (score 3):

You have multiple calls to malloc, which means your 3d array is not contiguous in memory. Thus memcpy cannot handle it all at once.

If you had allocated your 3d array in a contiguous fashion:

`malloc(sizeof(float) * ntab * ncrss * nsubs)`

then memcpy would work.

Comment: The full line could be `float (*b)[ncrss][ntab] = malloc( sizeof(float[nsubs][ncrss][ntab]) );`

Comment: Thanks for your clear explanation .It's a pity that I olny can choose one accepted answer.